# Prove $\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \ln \left(x^{2} + (\ln\cos x)^2 \right) \, dx=\pi\ln\ln2 $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, closed-form

> How to prove
>   $$
> \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln\left(\,x^{2} + \ln^{2}\left(\,\cos\left(\,x\,\right)\,\right) \,\right)\,{\rm d}x\ =\ \pi\ln\left(\,\ln\left(\, 2\,\right)\,\right)
> $$

I don't know how to answer it.

When I asked this integral to my brother, after less than half hours he said it has a nice closed-form involving $\pi$ and $\ln\left(2\right)$ but, as always, he didn't tell me the closed-form and how to obtain it ( I didn't believe him and I think he tried to mess around with me ).

I have also searched the similar question here but it looks like nothing is similar or related.

Could anyone here please help me to obtain the closed form of the integral preferably with elementary ways ( high school methods )?. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

---

**Edit:**

He is being a little bit nice to me today, he said the closed form is $\pi\ln\ln2$ and it's numerically correct.

This is not a duplicate problem, **I am looking for a proof without using complex analysis.**

Comment: I have no idea, but perhaps you can use the identity $\Re(\ln(x+iy))=\dfrac12\ln(x^2+y^2)$ where $x,y\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: The indefinite integral can be written as $$x\log\left(x^2+\log^2\cos x\right) - \int\dfrac{2x\left(x-\tan (x)\log\cos x\right)}{x^2+\log^2\cos x}\,dx$$ Note that if $f(x)$ is the denominator then the numerator is $xf'(x)$

Comment: This looks simpler
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \ln \left(x^{2} + \ln^{2}\cos x \right) \, dx=2 \Re \left[\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \ln \ln \left( \frac{1 + e^{2ix}}{2} \right) \, dx\right] $$

Comment: @imranfat I got stuck trying to solve for $x$ in $t=x^2+\log^2\cos x$

Comment: @Darksonn But that first part you don't need to integrate that. I assume that's what you meant? That's plug in work, and since it is an improper integral, you may have to work with L'Hospital or something. For the second one, if the num is the derivative of the denom, that would become an ln term?

Comment: [Wolframalpha]( http://wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate+ln%28x%5E2%2B%28ln%28cos%28x%29%29%29%5E2%29+from+0+to+pi%2F2&x=0&y=0) doesn't even return an exact value or give a closed form for the indefinite integral. So calculus level is pretty much impossible, and there is some definite chain pulling going on here.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy While I don't want to dispute that generally, I have come across integrals that were doable with normal integration but the computersystems couldn't do it. If (and only IF) Darksonn's approach works, that should be the way...That would also explain the double ln in the answer.

Comment: @imranfat True. And in any case I'm sure one of the resident integral masters will crack it and get many upvotes.

Comment: @Darksonn  That factor $x$ in the num creates a problem here...

Comment: @imranfat If $f(x)=x^2+\log^2\cos x$ and $t=x^2+\log^2\cos x$ then the integral is equal to $$x\log(x^2+\log^2\cos x)-\int\dfrac{f^{-1}(t)}{t}\,dt$$ where $f^{-1}(x)$ is the inverse of $f(x)$

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to
[make it take up less vertical space](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) --
this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main
page is distributed evenly over the questions.
See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730)
for more information. Please take this into consideration for future
questions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is a real-analytic method.

We have

> $$
> \int_{0}^{\Large \frac{\pi}{2}} \ln \left(x^{2} + \ln^2\cos x\right) \, {\rm d}x=\pi\ln(\ln2) \tag1
> $$

*Proof.* Let $s$ be a real number such that $-1<s<1$. One may use the following theorem ([proved here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/884021/ramanujan-log-trigonometric-integrals/943593#943593))
$$
\int_{0}^{\Large \frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\cos \left( s \arctan \left(\frac{x}{-\ln \cos x}\right)\right)}{(x^2+\ln^2\! \cos x)^{s/2}} \mathrm{d}x = \frac{\pi}{2}\frac{1}{\ln^{s}\!2}. \tag2
$$

We are then allowed to differentiate both sides of $(2)$
$$
\begin{align}
\partial_s \left. \left( \frac{\cos \left( s \arctan \left(\frac{x}{-\ln \cos x}\right)\right)}{(x^2+\ln^2\! \cos x)^{s/2}}\right) \right|_{s=0} &=-\frac 12 \ln \left(x^{2} + \ln^2\cos x\right) \\\\
\partial_s \left. \left( \frac{\pi}{2}\frac{1}{\ln^{s}\!2}\right) \right|_{s=0} &=-\frac{\pi}{2}\ln(\ln2)
\end{align}
$$
which gives the result $(1)$.

Comment: Wow! Very brilliant! +1

Comment: This is brilliant. Can you please look at my solution and let me know if it is incorrect? Many thanks!

Answer (score 16):

As noted in the comments, the integral is:
$$2\Re\int_0^{\pi/2} \ln\ln\left(\frac{1+e^{2ix}}{2}\right)\,dx=2\Re\int_0^{\pi/2} \ln\left(\ln\left(1+e^{2ix}\right)-\ln 2\right)\,dx$$
Consider 
$$f(x)=\ln(\ln(1+x)-\ln2)$$
Around $x=0$, the taylor expansion can be written as:
$$f(x)=f(0)+f'(0)x+f''(0)\frac{x^2}{2!}+f'''(0)\frac{x^3}{3!}+....$$
Replace $x$ with $e^{2ix}$. Notice that integrating the powers of $e^{2ix}$ would result in either zero or a purely imaginary number and since the derivatives of $f(x)$ at $0$ are real, we need to consider only the constant term i.e $f(0)$. Since $f(0)=\ln(-\ln 2)=\ln\ln 2+i\pi$, hence,
$$2\Re\int_0^{\pi/2} \ln\left(\ln\left(1+e^{2ix}\right)-\ln 2\right)\,dx=2\int_0^{\pi/2} \ln\ln 2\,dx=\boxed{\pi\ln\ln 2}$$

$\blacksquare$

Comment: Very nice Pranav! This is brilliant answer!! d(ˆ▽ˆ)b

Comment: Summon @VladimirReshetnikov! （‐＾▽＾‐）

Comment: Wait!? I'm missing something here. You said $f(x)=\ln(\ln(1+e^{\large2ix})-\ln2)$, right? But, then $f(0)\to-\infty$.

Comment: Nope, look at f(x) again.

Comment: Does the series converge ?. I'm worry about it because $\left\vert\,{\rm e}^{2{\rm i}x}\,\right\vert = 1$.

Comment: Indeed, I agree with Mr. @FelixMarin. I think the correct form for Taylor expansion should be
$$f(x)=f(x)\bigg|_{x=0}+f'(x)\bigg|_{x=0}x+ f''(x)\bigg|_{x=0} \frac{x^2}{2!} + \cdots$$
Hence
$$f(e^{2ix})=f(e^{2ix})\bigg|_{x=0}+f'(e^{2ix})\bigg|_{x=0}(e^{2ix}) + f''(e^{2ix})\bigg|_{x=0} \frac{(e^{2ix})^2}{2!} + \cdots$$

Comment: @PranavArora Thank you for the compliment. Concerning your answer, it would be nice to tell which determination you considered for $\log(x)$ and it would be nice to justify why you are allowed to switch $\int$ and $\sum$.

Comment: @OlivierOloa: Sorry, I do not know what does "determination for $\log(x)$" mean. About switching $\int$ and $\sum$, I did not do that, I integrate term by term. I integrated the first few powers to see that they result in either zero or an imaginary number so I kept only the first term and took the real part. Can you please answer the questions raised by OP and Felix? I do not have much knowledge about convergence of series and expansions, thanks!

Comment: @PranavArora You said "I integrated the first few powers to see that they result in either zero or an imaginary number so I kept only the first term and took the real part." This is the point: is the integral of the rest of your series really tending to  zero? I think yes it is, but I won't prove it now. Your reasoning is similar to the one I had given in my answer to your question about $\int_0^{\pi} \frac{x}{x^2+\ln^2(2\sin x)}\,dx,$ that's why I had dwelt with convergence issue there. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A solution using complex analysis is given [here](http://sos440.tistory.com/404) by [sos440](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/9340/sos440).

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I'm looking for real analysis method. +1 anyway (>‿◠)✌