# Inverse of $x^2+\log^2\cos x$

Tags: logarithms, inverse

I'm looking for the inverse of

$$f(x)=x^2+(\log\cos x)^2$$

Where $f$ is defined from $[0,\pi/2)$

It dosen't have to be closed form, a sum, an integral or some special functions would be of interest too.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal I tried WA and sagemath, but none of them can solve it, and I know no theorems I can use.

Comment: Where did this problem come from?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal From [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/915175/132791), read the comments of the post

Comment: Would it be ok to invert the function over a smaller interval?

Comment: @TymaGaidash Sure, that's better than nothing.