Finding a closed form for $ \int_0^1 \frac1x \ln\left(\frac{\ln\left(\frac{1-x}{2}\right)}{\ln\left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)}\right)\, \mathrm{d}x $
I want a closed form for the following integral
$$
\int_0^1 \frac1x\;\ln\left(\frac {\ln\left(\frac{1-x}{2}\right)}{\ln\left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)}\right)\, \mathrm{d}x
$$
An integration by parts attempt on my end led to the following integral
$$
\int_0^1 \frac1x \;\ln\left(\frac{\ln\left(\frac{1-x}{2}\right)}{\ln\left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)}\right) \, \mathrm{d}x 
= \int_0^1 \ln(x)\left(\frac{1}{(1-x)\ln\left(\frac{1-x}{2}\right)} 
+ \frac{1}{(1+x)\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{2}\right)}\right) \, \mathrm{d}x
$$
I have seen variations of these integrals, and usually they are solved by Feynman's trick.  I think the first one admits to a nice result, but I am not sure on how to handle the second one. If anyone has any ideas please let me know, there might be a substitution I am not seeing?
Apologies for the small integral sign for such a big integrand, I am unsure on how to make them bigger.

Unsure if this will help, but if you make the substitution:
$$ t =\frac{1 +  x}{2}$$
Then the Integral becomes:
$$
2\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 \frac{1}{2t - 1}\ln\left( \frac{\ln\left(1 - t\right)}{\ln\left(t\right)}\right):dt
$$

What is the source of the integral?

Hello, so I was gonna post more of my work as I went on, but this problem originated from me looking deeper into the following  integral.                                          https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/915175/prove-int-0-pi-2-ln-leftx2-ln-cos-x2-right-dx-pi-ln-ln2
If you look at the second answer, we reasoned that the integrand is the real part of some other complex logarithm, and then used a power series argument for his solution.  This integral comes about if you try to look for the Imaginary part of that complex logarithm, and then integrate over that function.

The imaginary part is given here through some of my work, but if you integrate over that function, you get an identical answer to the given integral here, up to a factor of -1/2 anyways.  I’ll add more as I discover more, but was able to at least show that much.

any further progress?

@Martin.s Hello, the most I was able to arrive at was an integral representation of part of the solution.  I will try to post what I have found in the coming weeks, though I will need to consult my notes.
