# Compute the fourier coefficients, and series for $\log(\sin(x))$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, fourier-series

I posted a similar question with a bad response, so I am retrying with hopes of better knowledge. The fourier series is in the form:

$$f(x) = \frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n\cos(nx) + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n\sin(nx)$$

Where:

$$a_n = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x)\cos(nx) dx$$
$$b_n = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x)\sin(nx) dx$$

The problem is computing the coefficients. **The goal of trying to derive the series is to solve:**

$$\int_{0}^{\pi} \log(\sin(x)) dx$$

$\displaystyle a_n = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \log(\sin(x))\cos(nx) dx$

Which is very difficult to compute.

What can be done?

The series representation is:

$$\log(\sin(x)) = -\log(2) - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(2kx)}{k}$$

Comment: Notice that $a_n$ is not so difficult to compute, if one performs a round of integration by parts, bringing the logarithm into a cotangent and the cosine into a sine.

Comment: The only slightly tricky part is to compute $a_0$, but there is a nice proof through Riemann sums. I will be glad to show it, as soon as I have enough time (quite busy at the moment).

Comment: exactly, integrating by parts we can just replace $\log\sin x$ with $\cot x$. After that, we just need Briggs' formulas to compute $a_k$ for $k\geq 1$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, it is very hard to compute the integral. I came up with:

$$I = \bigg[\log(\sin(x))\sin(nx)/n\bigg]_{-\pi}^{\pi} - \frac{1}{n}\cdot \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{\sin(nx)\cos(x)}{\sin(x)} dx$$

But the integral on the RHS does not converge

Comment: look carefully. $\frac{\sin(nx)}{\sin x}$ is a regular function that can be written as a sum of cosines.

Comment: Moreover, the integration range should be $[0,\pi]$ since the usual logarithm is not defined on $\mathbb{R}^-$. I ask you just a little patience, a couple of hours from now and I'll put all the details together.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ok, here I am. The goal is to compute the Fourier series of $g(x)=\log\sin x$ over $[0,\pi]$, or the Fourier series of $h(x)=\log\sin\frac{x}{2}$ over $[0,2\pi]$, or the Fourier series of $f(x)=\log\cos\frac{x}{2}$ over $[-\pi,\pi]$. Since $f(x)$ is an even function, we have to compute:
$$ a_n = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{+\pi}\cos(nx)\log\cos\frac{x}{2}\,dx = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos(nx)\log\cos\frac{x}{2}\,dx$$
for any $n\geq 1$ to be able to state:
$$ f(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\,dx + \sum_{n\geq 1}a_n\cos(nx)=\frac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{n\geq 1}a_n\cos(nx).$$
for any $x\in(-\pi,\pi)$. Integration by parts gives:
$$ a_n = \frac{2}{\pi}\left(\frac{1}{n}\left.\sin(nx)\log\cos\frac{x}{2}\right|_{0}^{\pi}+\frac{1}{2n}\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin(nx)\tan\frac{x}{2}\,dx\right)$$
or just:
$$ a_n = \frac{1}{\pi n}\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin(nx)\sin(x/2)}{\cos(x/2)}\,dx = \frac{2}{\pi n}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin(2nx)\sin x}{\cos x}\,dx.$$
Since $\cos((2n+1)x)=2\cos x\cos(2nx)-\cos((2n-1)x)$, we have:
$$ a_n = \frac{1}{\pi n}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\cos((2k-1)x)\,dx =\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}.$$
This gives:
$$\log\cos\frac{x}{2}=\frac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\cos(nx)$$
for any $x\in(-\pi,\pi)$. In order to find $a_0$, we can simply match $f(0)=0$ with the series on the right hand side. Since:
$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{1+x}=\log 2,$$
we have:
$$\log\cos\frac{x}{2}=-\log 2+\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\cos(nx)\qquad\forall x\in(-\pi,\pi),\tag{1}$$
and by translating the variable:
$$\log\sin\frac{x}{2}=-\log 2-\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n}\cos(nx)\qquad\forall x\in(0,2\pi),\tag{2}$$
$$\log\sin x = -\log 2-\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n}\cos(2nx)\qquad\forall x\in(0,\pi),\tag{3}$$
as wanted.

---

A little addendum, since I think it is worth mentioning the following technique. Starting with a celebrated identity:
$$\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\sin\frac{\pi k}{n}=\frac{2n}{2^n}$$
and noticing that $\log\sin x$ is a Riemann integrable function over $(0,\pi)$, we have:
$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\log\sin x\,dx = \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{\pi}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\log\sin\frac{\pi k}{n}=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{\pi}{n}\log\frac{2n}{2^n}=\color{red}{-\pi\log 2}.$$

Comment: Hey, I lost it here $\cos((2n+1)x)=2\cos x\cos(2nx)-\cos((2n-1)x)$ would you care to explain how this is true? And how do you see that the integral is that series?

Comment: @PedroFernandes For the first question use the exponential representation of $\cos$: \begin{align*}
        \cos(n x)
        & = \frac{1}{2} \left( e^{i n x} - e^{- i n x}\right) \\
        & = \frac{1}{2} \left( e^{i (n - 1) x} + e^{- i (n - 1) x}\right)\left(e^{i x} + e^{- i x}\right) - \frac{1}{2} \left( e^{i (n - 2) x} + e^{- i (n - 2) x}\right) \\
        & = 2 \cos((n - 1) x) \cos(x) - \cos((n - 2) x).
    \end{align*}

Answer (score 8):

Use equation $\text{(1d)}$ below and the fact that
$$
\int_0^\pi\cos(2kx)\,\mathrm{d}x=0
$$
to get
$$
\int_0^\pi\log(\sin(x))\,\mathrm{d}x=-\pi\log(2)
$$

---

$$
\begin{align}
\log(\sin(x))
&=\log\left(\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}\right)\tag{1a}\\
&=+ix-\log(2)-i\pi/2+\log(1-e^{-2ix})\tag{1b}\\
&=-ix-\log(2)+i\pi/2+\log(1-e^{+2ix})\tag{1c}\\
&=-\log(2)-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(2kx)}{k}\tag{1d}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(1a)}$: $\sin(x)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$
$\text{(1b)}$: bring $e^{+ix}$ and $+\frac1{2i}$ out of the log
$\text{(1c)}$: bring $e^{-ix}$ and $-\frac1{2i}$ out of the log
$\text{(1d)}$: use $\log(1-x)=-\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^k}k$ while averaging $\text{(1b)}$ and $\text{(1c)}$

---

$$
\begin{align}
\log(\cos(x))
&=\log\left(\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}2\right)\tag{2a}\\
&=+ix-\log(2)+\log(1+e^{-2ix})\tag{2b}\\
&=-ix-\log(2)+\log(1+e^{+2ix})\tag{2c}\\
&=-\log(2)+\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k-1}\frac{\cos(2kx)}{k}\tag{2d}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(2a)}$: $\cos(x)=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}2$
$\text{(2b)}$: bring $e^{+ix}$ and $\frac12$ out of the log
$\text{(2c)}$: bring $e^{-ix}$ and $\frac12$ out of the log
$\text{(2d)}$: use $\log(1+x)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k-1}\frac{x^k}k$ while averaging $\text{(2b)}$ and $\text{(2c)}$

Comment: I just ran across [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/978188) in which I prove equation $\text{(1d)}$ in a different way.

Comment: Hi Rob.  Happy Holidays.  Whenever I see one write $\log (z_1z_2)=\log(z_1)+\log(z_2)$ without specifying the branches that are assumed, I begin to wonder if the analysis is sound.  Of course, here one only needs to ensure that the branches of $\log(1-e^{\pm i2x})$ are chosen to make the right-hand sides purely real.  What did you have in mind?

Comment: @MarkViola: I assumed the branch cut along the negative real axis and standard log along the positive real axis. For small $x$, things are within a narrow cone about the real axis and so there should be little problem using $\log(xy)=\log(x)+\log(y)$.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}&\dsc{\sum_{k\ = 0}^{n}\exp\pars{2ky\ic}}
=\sum_{k\ = 0}^{n}\bracks{\exp\pars{2y\ic}}^{k}
={1 - \exp\pars{\bracks{n + 1}\bracks{2y\ic}} \over 1 - \exp\pars{2y\ic}}
\\[5mm]&={\exp\pars{-y\ic} - \exp\pars{\bracks{2n + 1}y\ic}\over
\exp\pars{-y\ic} - \exp\pars{y\ic}}
=\dsc{\half\,\ic\,{\exp\pars{-y\ic} - \exp\pars{\bracks{2n + 1}y\ic} \over \sin\pars{y}}}
\end{align}

> We'll take the *imaginary part* in both members:
>   \begin{align}&\sum_{k\ = 1}^{n}\sin\pars{2ky}
> =\half\,\cot\pars{y} - {\cos\pars{\bracks{2n + 1}y} \over 2\sin\pars{y}}
> \end{align}

With $\ds{0 < x \leq {\pi \over 2}}$, integrate in both members over
$\ds{\pars{x,{\pi \over 2}}}$:
\begin{align}&\sum_{k\ = 1}^{n}
{-\cos\pars{2k\bracks{\pi/2}} + \cos\pars{2kx} \over 2k}
=\left.\half\,\ln\pars{\sin\pars{y}}\right\vert_{x}^{\pi/2}
-\half\int_{x}^{\pi/2}{\cos\pars{\bracks{2n + 1}y} \over \sin\pars{y}}\,\dd y
\end{align}

> Then,
>   \begin{align}-\ \overbrace{\sum_{k\ = 1}^{n}{\pars{-1}^{k}\over k}}
> ^{\dsc{-\ln\pars{2}}}
> +\sum_{k\ = 1}^{n}{\cos\pars{2kx} \over k}
> =-\ln\pars{\sin\pars{x}}
> -\int_{x}^{\pi/2}{\cos\pars{\bracks{2n + 1}y} \over \sin\pars{y}}\,\dd y
> \end{align}

We'll take the limit $\ds{n \to\ \infty}$:
\begin{align}\ln\pars{\sin\pars{x}}&=
-\ln\pars{2} - \sum_{k\ = 1}^{\infty}{\cos\pars{2kx} \over k}\
-\ \underbrace{\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}
\int_{x}^{\pi/2}{\cos\pars{\bracks{2n + 1}y} \over \sin\pars{y}}\,\dd y}_{\ds{=}\ \dsc{0}}
\end{align}

> $$
> \color{#66f}{\large\ln\pars{\sin\pars{x}}}=
> \color{#66f}{\large-\ln\pars{2} - \sum_{k\ = 1}^{\infty}{\cos\pars{2kx} \over k}}
> \,,\qquad x \in \left(\, 0,{\pi \over 2}\,\right]\tag{1}
> $$
>   Indeed $\ds{\large\it\mbox{it's still valid}}$ in $\pars{0,\pi}$
>   $\ds{\pars{~\color{#00f}{\sf\mbox{see below}}~}}$

When $\ds{x \in \pars{{\pi \over 2},\pi}}$:
\begin{align}
\ln\pars{\sin\pars{x}}&=\ln\pars{\sin\pars{\pi - x}}
=-\ln\pars{2} - \sum_{k\ = 1}^{\infty}{\cos\pars{2k\bracks{\pi - x}} \over k}
\\[5mm]&=-\ln\pars{2} - \sum_{k\ = 1}^{\infty}{\cos\pars{2kx} \over k}
\end{align}
such that $\pars{1}$ is valid in $\pars{0,\pi}$.