# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x\ln(\tan(x))dx $

Tags: calculus, integration

How do I evaluate:
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x\ln(\tan(x))dx $$
I know it equals $\frac{7\zeta(3)}{8}$, but I'm not sure how to get there. I've been trying to convert it into a sum somehow, but I'm not getting anywhere. Equivalent integrals are:
$$\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty x\operatorname{sech}(x)\arctan(e^x)dx$$
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan(x)\ln(x)}{1+x^2} dx$$

I've tried differentiating under the integral but to no avail.

Comment: The integral appeared here: [$\int_{0}^{\pi }\theta \ln\tan\frac{\theta }{2} \, \mathrm{d}\theta$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1634265/how-to-evaluate-int-0-pi-theta-ln-tan-frac-theta-2-mathrmd-th)

Comment: Here is a reference: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/330057/how-to-evaluate-i-int-0-pi-2x2-ln-sin-x-ln-cos-x-mathrm-dx?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @Zacky ah yes thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> $$\mathfrak{I}=\int_0^{\pi/2} x\log(\tan x )dx=\frac78\zeta(3)\tag1$$

The idea of converting it into a sum is good! Appropriate in this case are the Fourier Expansions of $\log(\sin x)$ and $\log(\cos x)$ since we can rewrite $\log(\tan x)$ as $\log(\sin x)-\log(\cos x)$. These Series are given by

$$\begin{align}
\log(\sin x)&=-\log(2)-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(2nx)}{n}\\
\log(\cos x)&=-\log(2)-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{\cos(2nx)}{n}
\end{align}$$

Plugging these series in $\mathfrak{I}$ yields to

$$\small\begin{align}
\mathfrak{I}=\int_0^{\pi/2} x\log(\tan x )dx&=\int_0^{\pi/2} x(\log(\sin x )-\log(\cos x))dx\\
&=\int_0^{\pi/2}x\left(-\log(2)-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(2nx)}{n}+\log(2)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{\cos(2nx)}{n}\right)dx\\
&=\int_0^{\pi/2}x\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{\cos(2nx)}{n}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(2nx)}{n}\right)dx
\end{align}$$

Hence the given Fourier Series converge within the interval $[0,\pi]$ we may interchange the order of summation and integration which leaves with a rather simple integral which can be done using only Integration by Parts. So we further get

$$\begin{align}
\mathfrak{I}&=\int_0^{\pi/2}x\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{\cos(2nx)}{n}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(2nx)}n\right)dx\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}n\underbrace{\int_0^{\pi/2}x\cos(2nx)dx}_{=I}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1n\underbrace{\int_0^{\pi/2}x\cos(2nx)dx}_{=I}
\end{align}$$

The inner integral can be evaluated fairly easy as already mentioned applying Integration by Parts. It turns out that this integral equals

$$I=\int_0^{\pi/2}x\cos(2nx)dx=\frac{\pi\sin(n\pi)}{4n}+\frac{\cos(n\pi)}{4n^2}-\frac1{4n^2}$$

The sine term vanishs directly since $\sin(n\pi)=0~\forall n\in\mathbb N$. The $\cos(n\pi)$ on the other hand oscillates between $1$ and $-1$ depending on whether $n$ is even or odd. Putting this together leads to

$$\begin{align}
\mathfrak{I}&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}n\left[\frac{\pi\sin(n\pi)}{4n}+\frac{\cos(n\pi)}{4n^2}-\frac1{4n^2}\right]-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1n\left[\frac{\pi\sin(n\pi)}{4n}+\frac{\cos(n\pi)}{4n^2}-\frac1{4n^2}\right]\\
&=\frac14\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}n\left[\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}-\frac1{n^2}\right]-\frac14\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1n\left[\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}-\frac1{n^2}\right]\\
&=\frac14\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{n^3}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^3}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^3}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{n^3}\right)\\
&=\frac12(\zeta(3)+\eta(3))\\
&=\frac78\zeta(3)
\end{align}$$

That we can split the sum here can be justified due the absolute convergence of the given series. Within the last few steps we utilized the Dirichlet Eta Function $\eta(s)$ and its quite simple relation to the Riemann Zeta Function $\zeta(s)$, namely $\eta(s)=(1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s)$. And so it follows that

> $$\therefore\mathfrak{I}=\int_0^{\pi/2} x\log(\tan x )dx=\frac78\zeta(3)$$

Comment: This is explained pretty clearly. I would say it's a good thing that question are duplicated sometimes.

Comment: @Zacky Thank you kindly. I appreciate your compliment as I know you are an ardent admirer of integrals aswell `^^`

Comment: Can this method be generalized to solve related integrals like $ \int_{0}^{\pi/2}x^{2}\ln^{2}\tan x\,\mathrm{d}x $?

Comment: @Ininterrompue: Yes, but it requires some other techniques.

Comment: @Ininterrompue This method I proposed can be used to evaluate integrals of the tpye $\int_0^{\pi/2}x^k\log(\tan x)dx$ $($for $k\in\mathbb Z$$)$ since it reduces the problem to $\int x^k \cos(2nx)dx$ which can be *always* done by IBP. But as Larry aready mentioned this fails $($at least it is not that simple done$)$ for powers of the logarithm hence it would produce double series which are in my opinion harder to handle.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**
Rewrite your original integral into
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}x\ln\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}\right)dx=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}x(\ln(\sin(x))-\ln({\cos(x)}))dx$$
And use Fourier Series
$$\ln(\sin(x))=-\ln(2)-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(2kx)}{k}$$
$$\ln(\cos(x))=-\ln(2)-\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{\cos(2kx)}{k}$$