# Is there a closed form of $\int_0^{+\infty} t^n \cos (\pi t) e^{-m t}dt$ for any non-negative integer $n$ and $m>0$?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, trigonometry, improper-integrals

Instead, let’s first evaluate the integral
$\displaystyle I(a)=\int_0^{\infty} \cos (\pi t) e^{-a t} d t \tag*{} $
where $a>0$.
Using Euler identity : $e^{xi}=\cos x+i\sin x$, we have

$\displaystyle \begin{aligned}I(a) & =\int_0^{\infty} \cos (\pi t) e^{-a t} d t \\& =\Re \int_0^{\infty} e^{(\pi i-a) t} d t \\& =\Re\left[\frac{e^{(\pi i-a) t}}{\pi i-a}\right]_0^{\infty} \\& =\Re\left(\frac{1}{a-\pi i}\right) \\& =\frac{a}{a^2+\pi^2}\end{aligned}\tag*{} $

Then differentiating $I(a)$ w.r.t. $a$ yields
$\displaystyle I^{\prime}(a)=-\int_0^{+\infty} t \cos (\pi t) e^{-a t} d t= \frac{a^2-\pi^2}{\left(a^2+\pi^2\right)^2}\tag*{} $

Again, differentiating $I’(a)$ w.r.t. $a$ further gives
$\displaystyle I^{\prime \prime}(a)=\int_0^{+\infty} t^2 \cos (\pi t) e^{-a t} d t= \frac{2 a\left(a^2-3 \pi^2\right)}{\left(a^2+\pi^2\right)^3}\tag*{} $

In general, for any non-negative integer $n$ and $m>0.$

$\displaystyle \boxed{ \left.\int_0^{+\infty} t^n \cos (\pi t) e^{-m t}dt=(-1)^n \frac{d^n}{d a^n}\left(\frac{a}{a^2+\pi^2}\right)\right|_{a=m}}\tag*{} $

**My Question**

Is there a closed form for
$$\int_0^{+\infty} t^n \cos (\pi t) e^{-m t}dt \textrm{  or } \left.(-1)^n \frac{d^n}{d a^n}\left(\frac{a}{a^2+\pi^2}\right)\right|_{a=m}$$

for any non-negative integer $n$ and $m>0$?

Comment: Using *Mathematica* on the integral I get $n! \left(m^2+\pi ^2\right)^{-\frac{n}{2}-\frac{1}{2}} \cos \left((n+1) \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\pi }{m}\right)\right)$ using `Integrate[t^n Cos[t \[Pi]] Exp[-m t], {t, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> m \[Element] PositiveIntegers && n \[Element] PositiveIntegers]`.  I know you want a proof but sometimes knowing the answer will suggest a proof.

Comment: Third-line equation for $I(a)$ is equivalent to $\Re \frac{1}{ a-i \pi}$. Differentiate that wrt to $a$.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/977093/).

Comment: Thank you very much to the comments above.  @MathSensei, you light up my answer, thank you. I write the latest update as another answer now.

Comment: @JimB. This is true even for non integer $(m,n)$

Comment: Yes, it is a good news.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks!  That's good to know.  After your comment I removed both assumptions on $n$ and $m$ and got the same result but the with the restrictions that the real part of $n$ needs to be greater than -1 and the real part of $m$ needs to be greater than zero.  (I included the previous positive integer assumption because of the way the question was asked *and* because many times *Mathematica* is more likely to return a result with such explicit restrictions.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

\begin{align}
&\int_0^{+\infty} t^n \cos (\pi t) e^{-a t}dt \\
=&\ (-1)^n \frac{d^n}{d a^n}\left(\frac{a}{a^2+\pi^2}\right)
 = (-1)^n \frac{d^{n+1}}{d a^{n+1}}\Re \ln(a+i\pi)\\
=&\ 
 \Re \frac{n!}{(a+i\pi)^{n+1}} 
= \frac{n! \cos[(n+1)\tan^{-1}\frac{\pi}{a}]}{(a^2+\pi^2)^\frac{n+1}{2}}
\end{align}

Comment: Fast and elegant, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Let us define $$I_n(a) = \int_0^\infty t^n e^{-(a+i\pi)t} ~ dt$$ so that your integral equals the real part of $I_m(a)$. By integration by parts, for $n>0$, we get that $$I_n(a) = \frac{n}{a+i\pi}\int_0^\infty t^{n-1}e^{-(a+i\pi)t} ~ dt$$ which, by induction, gives us $$I_n(a) = \frac{n!}{(a+i\pi)^n}I_0(a) = \frac{n!}{(a+i\pi)^{n+1}}$$ We wish to extract the real part of this expression, and writing the denominator in polar coordinates shall help us with this. We have that $$a+i\pi = \sqrt{a^2+\pi^2}\exp\Big(i ~ \arctan\frac{\pi}{a}\Big)$$ hence $$(a+i\pi)^{n+1} = (a^2+\pi^2)^\tfrac{n+1}{2}\exp\Big((n+1)i ~ \arctan\frac{\pi}{a}\Big)$$ and therefore we have $$\color{green}{I_n(a) = \frac{n!}{(a^2+\pi^2)^\tfrac{n+1}{2}}\cos\Big((n+1)\arctan\frac{\pi}{a}}\Big)$$ in agreement with the answer provided by Mathematica in the comments!

Comment: Nice, a good demonstration of MI.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using Cauchy's integral theorem that slightly generalizes some of the other answers:
$$\boxed{\int_0^{\infty}t^{\alpha-1}\cos(\pi t)e^{-\beta t}\,dt = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha)}{(\beta^2 + \pi^2)^{\frac{\alpha}{2}}}\cos\left(\alpha\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\pi}{\beta}\right)\right), \quad\alpha, \beta > 0.}$$

Let $s = \sqrt{\beta^2+\pi^2}$ and $f(z) = z^{\alpha-1}e^{-sz}$ for $z\in \mathbb C$. Further, let $C$ be the union of the four counterclockwise paths
$$C_1 := \{xe^{i\theta} :x\in [\varepsilon,R]\}, \quad C_2 := \{Re^{ix}:x\in[0,\theta)\}, \quad C_3 := [\varepsilon,R], \quad C_4:=\{\varepsilon e^{ix} : \quad x\in [0,\theta)\}$$
where $\theta = \tan^{-1}(\pi/\beta)$ and $\varepsilon, R > 0$.
Then by Cauchy's theorem, $\int_C f(z)\,dz = 0$ for every $\varepsilon, R > 0$, hence taking $\varepsilon \to 0^+$ and $R \to \infty$ yields
$$e^{i\alpha\theta}\int_0^{\infty}t^{\alpha-1}e^{(\beta+i\pi)t}\,dt = \int_0^{\infty}t^{\alpha-1}e^{-st}\,dz = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha)}{s^{\alpha}},\quad (*)$$
where we used the facts
$$\lim_{R\to \infty}\left|\int_{C_2} f(z)\,dz\right| \leq \lim_{R\to \infty}R^{\alpha}\int_0^{\theta}e^{-sR\cos x}\,dx = 0,$$
$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\left|\int_{C_4} f(z)\,dz\right| \leq \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\varepsilon^{\alpha}\int_0^{\theta}e^{-s\varepsilon\cos x}\,dx = 0.$$ Taking the real parts in ($*$) yields the desired result.

Answer (score -1):

Franklin's recursive method can actually be extended to non integer values. In fact, on page 498 of the 11th edition of [Table of Intgrals, Series, and Products](http://fisica.ciens.ucv.ve/%7Esvincenz/TISPISGIMR.pdf) there appears the very general integral (identity 4)
$$\int_0^z x^{a-1}\mathrm e^{-bx}\cos(cx)\mathrm dx=\frac{1}{2}(b+\mathrm ic)^{-a}~\gamma\big(a,(b+\mathrm ic)z\big)+\frac{1}{2}(b-\mathrm ic)^{-a}~\gamma\big(a,(b-\mathrm ic)z\big)$$

Where $\gamma(\cdot,\cdot)$ is a lower [incomplete Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function).

Taking the special case $z\to\infty$, (identity 6)  $a=p+1$, $b=q$, $c=\pi$, we get
$$\phi(p,q)=\int_0^\infty t^{p} \cos(\pi t)\mathrm e^{-qt}\mathrm dt \\ =\boxed{\frac{\Gamma(p+1)}{(q^2+\pi^2)^{\frac{p+1}{2}}}\cos\left((p+1)\arctan\frac{\pi}{q}\right)}$$

Answer (score -2):

As @ MathSensei suggested, I can now write a closed form for the integral as
$$
\boxed{\int_0^{+\infty} t^n \cos (\pi t) e^{-at}dt =I^{(n)}(a)=\frac{ n !}{\left(a^2+\pi^2\right)^{\frac{n+1}{2}}}\left[\cos (n+1) \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\pi}{a}\right)\right]}
$$
by differentiating $I(a)=\Re\left(\frac{1}{a-\pi i}\right)$ w.r.t. $a$ by $n$ times as
$$
\begin{aligned}
I^{(n)}(a) & =\Re\left[\frac{d^n}{d a^n}\left(\frac{1}{a-\pi i}\right)\right] =\Re\left[\frac{(-1)^n n!}{(a-\pi i)^{n+1}}\right]
\end{aligned}
$$
Expressing the last term in terms of polar form yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
(a-\pi i)^{n+1} & =\left[\sqrt{a^2+\pi^2} e^{-i \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\pi}{a}\right)}\right]^{n+1} \\
& =\left(a^2+\pi^2\right)^{\frac{n+1}{2}} e^{-i(n+1) \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\pi}{a}\right)}
\end{aligned}
$$
and complete the proof that
$$
\int_0^{+\infty} t^n \cos (\pi t) e^{-a t} d t=(-1)^n \frac{d^n}{d a^n} \Re\left(\frac{1}{a-\pi i}\right)= \frac{ n !}{\left(a^2+\pi^2\right)^{\frac{n+1}{2}}}\left[\cos (n+1) \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\pi}{a}\right)\right]
$$