# Can we compute $\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\sin ^2(\ln x)}{x^2 \ln ^2 x} d x$ without Feynman’s trick?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

When I came across the integral

$$I=\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\sin ^2(\ln x)}{x^2 \ln ^2 x} d x,$$

I immediately thought of the Feynman’s trick after the substitution $x\mapsto \frac{1}{x}$.

$$
I=\int_0^1 \frac{\sin ^2(\ln x)}{\ln ^2 x} d x
$$

Considering the parameterised integral

$$
I(a)=\int_0^1 \frac{\sin ^2(a \ln x)}{\ln ^2 x} d x
$$
Differentiating $I(a)$ w.r.t. $a$ twice, we get

$$
I^{\prime}(a)=\int_0^1 \frac{\sin (2a \ln x)}{\ln x}dx
$$
and $$
I^{\prime \prime}(a) =2 \int_0^1 \cos (2 a \ln x) d x =\frac{2}{4 a^2+1}
$$
Integrating back yields
$$
I ^{\prime}(a)=I^{\prime}(a)-I^{\prime}(0)= \int_0^a \frac{2}{4 t^2+1} d t =\tan ^{-1}(2 a)
$$
Further integration gives
$$
\boxed{\int_0^1 \frac{\sin ^2(a \ln x)}{\ln ^2 x} d x =\int_0^a \tan ^{-1}(2 t) d t=a \tan ^{-1}(2 a)-\frac{1}{4} \ln \left(4 a^2+1\right)}
$$
Now we can conclude that
$$\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\sin ^2(\ln x)}{x^2 \ln ^2 x} d x =I(1)= 
\tan ^{-1} 2-\frac{\ln 5}{4}
$$

**My question:**

Can we compute $$\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\sin ^2(\ln x)}{x^2 \ln ^2 x} d x$$ without Feynman’s trick?

Your comments and alternative methods are highly appreciated.

Comment: Probably $ sinx={e^{ix}-e^{-ix}\over 2i}$  can help

Comment: Substituting $x = \exp u$ transforms the integral to $\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-u} \sin^2 u \,du}{u^2}$, and rewriting $\sin$ in terms of $\exp$ as @user619894 suggests means that we can write an antiderivative explicitly in terms of the exponential integral function, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral. So, evaluating the integral turns into understanding the behavior of the exponential integral as $u \to 0$ and $u \to \infty$.

Comment: @TravisWillse my idea was simpler: keep $x$ but note that $x^{2+\epsilon}\sim x^2 + \epsilon x^2 ln(x)\cdots$

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using the following property of Laplace Transform
$$ \int_0^\infty (\mathcal Lf)(t)g(t)\mathrm dt=\int_0^\infty f(s)(\mathcal Lg)(s)\mathrm ds, \qquad\mathcal{L}\{t\}(s)=\frac1{s^2} ,$$
one has
\begin{eqnarray}
I&=&\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\sin ^2(\ln x)}{x^2 \ln ^2 x}\mathrm d x\overset{s=\ln x}{=}\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-s}\sin^2 s}{s^2}\mathrm ds\\
&=&\int_0^\infty e^{-s}\sin^2 s\mathcal L\{t\}(s)\mathrm ds\\
&=&\int_0^\infty \mathcal{L}\{e^{-s}\sin^2 s\}(t)t\mathrm dt\\
&=&\int_0^\infty\frac{2t}{(t+1)(t^2+2t+5)}\mathrm dt\\
&=&\int_1^\infty\frac{2(t-1)}{t(t^2+4)}\mathrm dt\\
&=&\arctan(2)-\frac14\ln5.
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 7):

You have shown (via $x\mapsto \frac{1}{x}$) that  $\displaystyle I=\int_0^1 \frac{\sin ^2(\ln x)}{\ln ^2 x} d x$

Now, observe that $\displaystyle \frac{\sin(\ln(x))  }{\ln{x}} = \int_0^1 \cos(t \ln{x}) \, \mathrm dt$

Then setting it up as a triple integral, we have:

$$\begin{aligned} I & := \int_0^1\frac{\sin^2(\ln(x))  }{\ln^2{x}}\, \mathrm dx \\&= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \cos(t\ln{x})  \cos(y\ln{x})\;{\mathrm dy}\;{\mathrm dt}\;{\mathrm dx} \\& = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \cos(t\ln{x})  \cos(y\ln{x})\;{\mathrm dx}\;{\mathrm dt}\;{\mathrm dy}  \\&= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{1 + t^2 + y^2}{t^4 - 2 t^2 (-1 + y^2) + (1 + y^2)^2} \ \;{\mathrm dt} \;{\mathrm dy}
\\& =  \int_0^1 \frac{1}{2} \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{y^2}\right)
 \;{\mathrm dy} \\& = \tan^{-1}(2) - \frac{\log(5)}{4}
.  \end{aligned}$$

You can fill in the details.

Answer (score 6):

Making the substitution $t = \ln(x)$ and then integrating by parts, we have

$$\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^{2}(\ln x)}{x^{2} \ln^{2}(x)} \, \mathrm dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t}\sin(2t)}{t} \, \mathrm dt - \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t} \sin^{2}(t)}{t} \, \mathrm dt.$$

Using the [integral formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/977142/16033) $$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-at} \sin(bt) t^{s-1} \, \mathrm dt = \frac{\Gamma(s)}{\left(a^{2}+b^{2} \right)^{s/2}} \, \sin \left(s \arctan \left(\frac{b}{a} \right) \right), $$ the value of the first integral is $$ \begin{align} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t}\sin(2t)}{t} \, \mathrm dt &= \lim_{s \to 0^{+}} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t} \sin(2t) t^{s-1} \, \mathrm dt \\ &= \lim_{s \to 0^{+}} \frac{\Gamma(s)}{5^{s/2}} \, \sin\left( s  \arctan  2 \right)  \\ &= \lim_{s \to 0^{+}} 5^{-s/2}\left(\frac{1}{s} + O(1) \right)\sin\left( s \arctan 2 \right) \\ &= \lim_{s \to 0^{+}} \frac{5^{-s/2} \sin \left(s \arctan 2 \right)}{s}     \\ &=\arctan(2).\end{align}$$

And using the [companion formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/977142/16033) $$ \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-at} \cos(bt) t^{s-1} \, \mathrm dt = \frac{\Gamma(s)}{\left(a^{2}+b^{2} \right)^{s/2}} \, \cos \left(s \arctan \left(\frac{b}{a} \right) \right), $$ the value of the second integral is $$ \begin{align} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t} \sin^{2}(t)}{t} \, \mathrm dt &= \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t}\left(1- \cos(2t)\right)}{t} \, \mathrm dt \\ &= \frac{1}{2}\lim_{s \to 0^{+}} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t} \left(1- \cos(2t) \right) t^{s-1} \, \mathrm dt \\ &= \frac{1}{2} \lim_{s \to 0^{+}} \left(\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t} t^{s-1} \, \mathrm dt - \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t} \cos(2t) t^{s-1} \, \mathrm dt\right)\\ &= \frac{1}{2} \lim_{s \to 0^{+}} \left(\Gamma(s) - \frac{\Gamma(s)}{5^{s/2}} \cos \left(s \arctan 2 \right)\right) \\ &= \frac{1}{2}\lim_{s \to 0^{+}}  \Gamma(s) \left(1- \frac{\cos \left(s \arctan 2\right)}{5^{s/2}} \right)\\ &= \frac{1}{2}\lim_{s \to 0^{+}} \left(\frac{1}{s} + O(1) \right)\left(1- \frac{\cos \left(s \arctan 2\right)}{5^{s/2}} \right)  \\ &= \frac{1}{2} \lim_{s \to 0^{+}} \frac{1- 5^{-s/2}\cos \left(s \arctan 2 \right)}{s}   \\ &= \frac{\ln(5)}{4}. \end{align}$$

Therefore, $$\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^{2}(\ln x)}{x^{2} \ln^{2}(x)} \, \mathrm dx = \arctan(2) - \frac{\ln (5)}{4}.  $$

---

Justification for bringing the limits inside the integrals comes from the dominated convergence theorem.

For $s \in [0, \alpha], \alpha>0 $, the function  $e^{-t} \sin(2t) t^{s-1}$ is dominated on the interval $(0,1]$ by the integrable function $\frac{e^{-t}|\sin(2t)|}{t}$ and dominated on the interval $(1, \infty)$ by the integrable function $e^{-t} t^{\alpha-1}$.

Similarly, the function  $e^{-t} \left(1- \cos(2t) \right) t^{s-1} $is dominated on the interval $(0, 1]$ by the  integrable function $\frac{e^{-t}|1-\cos(2t)|}{t} $ and dominated on the interval $(1, \infty)$ by the integrable function $2 e^{-t} t^{\alpha -1}$.

Answer (score 3):

This might be similar to your answer, but we can use the mapping $\ln x \mapsto x$ so that

$$
I := \int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^{2}\left(\ln x\right)}{x^{2}\ln^{2}x}dx = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^{2}x}{x^{2}e^{x}}dx\,.
$$

Using [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/Q_Sad4DAep4), we use the following Laplace transform:

$$
\mathscr{L}\left\{\frac{\sin^2t}{t}\right\}(s) = \mathscr{L}\left\{\frac{1-\cos2t}{t}\right\}(s) = \frac{1}{2}\int_{s}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{t}-\frac{t}{t^{2}+4}\right)dt = \frac{1}{4}\ln\left(\frac{s^{2}+4}{s^{2}}\right)\,.
$$

We can use the statement

$$
\mathscr{L}\left\{f(t)\right\}(s) = F(s) \implies \mathscr{L}\left\{\frac{f(t)}{t}\right\}(s) = \int_{s}^{\infty}F\left(t\right)dt
$$

and get

$$
I = \mathscr{L}\left\{\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}\right\}(1) = \int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4}\ln\left(\frac{t^{2}+4}{t^{2}}\right)dt \overset{IBP}=  \frac{1}{4}\left[t\ln\left(\frac{t^{2}+4}{t^{2}}\right)\right]_{1}^{\infty}+2\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{t^{2}+4}dt\,,
$$

which simplifies down to

$$
I = \arctan2-\frac{\ln5}{4}\,.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Letting $s=\ln x$ transforms the integral into $$
I=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-s} \sin ^2 s}{s^2} d s
$$
Then integration by parts on $\frac{1}{x^2}$  gives $$
I=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-s}\left(\sin 2 s-\sin ^2 s\right)}{s} d s
$$
Noting that $e^{-s}= \int_1^{\infty} e^{-t s} d t $, we have $$
\begin{aligned}
I &= \int_0^{\infty}\left[\left(\sin 2 s-\sin ^2 s\right) \int_1^{\infty} e^{-t s} d t\right] d s\\& =\int_1^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty}\left(\sin 2 s-\sin ^2 s\right) e^{-t s} d s d t \\
& =\int_1^{\infty}\left(\frac{2}{t^2+4}-\frac{2}{t(t^2+4 )}\right) d t  \\
& =\left[\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)-\frac{1}{4} \ln \left(\frac{t^2}{t^2+4}\right)\right]_1^{\infty} \\
& =\frac{\pi}{2}-\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{4} \ln \left(\frac{1}{5}\right) \\
& =\tan ^{-1} 2-\frac{\ln 5}{4}
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Trying to make the problem more general
$$I_n=\int_1^\infty\Bigg( \frac{\sin (\log (x)) }{x\,\log (x) }\Bigg)^n\,dx=\int_0^\infty e^{-(n-1)\,t} \,\left(\frac{\sin (t)}{t}\right)^n\,dt$$

Using Euler representation of the sine function and binomial expansions, this leads to exponential integrals (have a look [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Integrate%5BSin%5Bt%5D%5E2%2F%28E%5Et*t%5E2%29%2Ct%5D) for $n=2$).

The next ones are

$$I_3=\frac{5}{8} \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)+\frac{9}{8} \cot ^{-1}(2)-\frac{3}{4} \log \left(\frac{13}{5}\right)$$
$$I_4=\frac{23}{6} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)-\frac{11}{12} \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)-\frac{3}{16} \log \left(\frac{1220703125}{3326427}\right)$$